# spring Boot MongoDB Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have the following scenario:-

1. Use Device_Type telemetry for searching.
2. Should pull any Device that has a telemetry key that start with "processor".

Database used : Mongo DB

**Device_Type.Class (Field of Device_Type collection)**

```
@NotBlank
private String applicationId;
private AcnDeviceCategory deviceCategory;
private boolean editable = CoreConstant.DEFAULT_EDITABLE;
private List<DeviceTelemetry> telemetries = new ArrayList<>();
private Map<String, DeviceStateValueMetadata> stateMetadata = new HashMap<>();
private List<DeviceAction> actions = new ArrayList<>();
```

DeviceTelemetry.Class

```
private String name;
private String description;
@NotNull
private TelemetryItemType type;
private String telemetryUnitId;
private Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<>();
```

Device.class

```
@NotBlank
private String uid;
@NotBlank
private String name;

enter code here
```

My code query is something like this

```
    public static List<Device> getFilteredTelemetries(DeviceType deviceType) {
    List<DeviceTelemetry> telemetriesToAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    
    
        deviceType.getTelemetries().stream()
        .filter(f -> f.getName().startsWith("System_Processor"))
        .forEach(f -> {
            telemetriesToAdd.add(f);
        });
        deviceType.getTelemetries().addAll(telemetriesToAdd);
                        
    return null;
}
```

can anyone please help me, how I return the device list here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: for example - Telemetry -Laptop & Device - Dell , Hp, Macbook............. So I need list of device which have telemetry key as laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove if `!f.getName().startsWith("System_Processor")` from the list

```
deviceType.getTelemetries().stream()
    .removeIf(f -> !f.getName().startsWith("System_Processor"))
```

Comment: Okay , but I need to return query for device which can fetch all details of device.
return statement will look something like this :-
  Query query = new Query();
  // Have to Add some criteria      
  return this.getOperations().find(query, Device.class);

Comment: for example -

Telemetry -Laptop &
Device - Dell , Hp, Macbook.............

So I need list of device which have telemetry key as laptop.